# How to check who run/activate process that lock specific port before?

Tags: java, windows, tcp, process, tcplistener

I run java application that run jetty with port for example 9911.
After I run application I see that the port is already in use :

> 2012-08-07 10:36:06.848::WARN:  failed SslSocketConnector@localhost:9911
>   java.net.BindException: Address already in use: JVM_Bind

With **netstat** I get :

> ```
> TCP    NoamPc:9911            MyPc:0       LISTENING       1436
> ```

With **tcpView** I get :

> ```
> java.exe  1436    TCP 9999    MyPc    0   LISTENING
> ```

The process is run from : C:\dev\jdk1.6\bin\java.exe
in VirtualVM I cannot see any process...

I know that I can use with some other port number,
**But my question is how can I check in windows environment, who run/activate process that lock specific port before.**
Tnx

Comment: In general it's impossible to know *who* created a process that did whats-or-ever. AFAIK the "process creator" information is not kept in windows.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I find this useful application - *Process Monitor*

you can see processes running and executed, with process tree.
You can download it from http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb896645.aspx